# ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: time data 1 does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)

Tags: python, pandas

Working with Pandas dataframe with datetime function.  My data currently has the Year and Month column.  I need to create a datetime column so I can eventually join to another dataframe datetime.  Here is my data:

```
 Index  ID   Year  Month
 0      a14  2010  11
```

I try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month']],format='%Y%m')
```

Get the error:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day] is missing
```

So I add:

```
df['Day'] = 1
```

Retry the datetime function:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']],format='%Y%m%d')

 ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: time data 1 does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

Comment: You want a datetime value that spans several columns? How could you use that? You need a new column.

Comment: @Bachzen just tried to run your code and it works OK on pandas 0.23. Maybe you're using an old version?

Comment: @RafaelC  '0.23.0'

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is actually good, you don't need to paste the separate columns together.  Just get rid of your format string, Pandas is smart enough to figure it out.

Like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.assign(Day=1).drop(["Index", "ID"], 1))

0   2010-11-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or, to use your original code, once you've added `Day`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
```

See [`to_datetime()` documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for more on this way of building date objects.

Comment: I just checked, `format` works ok for me too (`0.23.3`).  I just didn't think to check initially.  Good call.